# Android Studio FileInputStream open failed: ENOENT

Tags: java, android

Android Studio: 1.0.2

I am new to Android Studio.  I have added the file "myFile.der" to app/src/main/assets directory and ensure the line

```
<option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
```

exists in the app.iml file.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myFile.der");
```

After running the program on the emulator, I got this error message:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: myFile.der: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I do not know what I have missed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileInputStream constructor does not know anything about your assets directory.

Use assets manager to open files from assets directory:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("myFile.der");
```